# Getting org.apache.poi.POIXMLException: org.apache.poi.openxml4j.exceptions.InvalidFormatException: Package should contain a content type part [M1.13]

Tags: java

I am trying to read an excel file. I have created one service and it is using apache POI. Its working fine if I am passing fileInputstream. I am uploading the excel using the servlet and from servlet I am calling my service by passing **request.getInputstream()** as inputStream. But not working . Its throwing the above exception. 
           so I tried another way by creating the excel file in server using the **request.getInputstream()**. After that I will create the FileInputstream using the created file. After that I am deleting the file. This is working fine. But I want to avoid creating file in server and then reading again. Is there any way to convert this HttpStream to FileinputStream? Or Is there any other option to pass the stream without creating the file?

Comment: I'm confused on what you are trying to do.  If you have the inputstream that contains the file content just use the XSSFWorkbook constructor that takes an input stream.

Comment: Hai Joseph,

I have tried with fileinputstream and its working. but if I want to pass file input stream then I want to write the file to the server and then I need to create the fileInputStream .But I want to avoid that by passing the request.getInputStream directly to the XssfWorkbook Constructor but its not working and I am getting the above exception.

Comment: Hmm are you sure your excel file is .xlsx extension?  POI has other classes for .xls